# Replacement for scrollTo and scrollToExact in java client v4.0

Tags: java, android, scroll, appium, swipe

I am writing Mobile App automation test cases for Android/iOS using java and appium.

I have upgraded my appium version from 3.1.0 to 4.0.0. Now I am not able use scrollTo() and scrollToExact()

Java client [ReadMe](https://github.com/appium/java-client) readme says the following:-
`scrollTo()` and `scrollToExact()` became deprecated. They are going to be removed in the next release.

Anyother method avaialble other than swipe method and 
like

```
((MobileElement)element).swipe(SwipeDirection.UP,100);
```

Does anyone know any possible methods for replacing `scrollTo` and `scrollToExact`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is deprecated because it is not consistent and it is going to be removed. It is workaround actually.
Recommended to use instead:

```
AppiumDriver.swipe(int, int, int, int, int)
MobileElement.swipe(SwipeElementDirection, int)   
MobileElement.swipe(SwipeElementDirection, int, int, int)
```

or search for elements using

```
MobileBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator
```

**Specified by:**

```
scrollTo in interface ScrollsTo<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
```

**Parameters:**
text - description or text of an element scroll to

**Returns:**
an element that matches

Now to user `swipe`

```
public abstract void swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration)
```

**Description copied from interface:**
TouchShortcuts
Convenience method for swiping across the screen.

**Parameters:**
startx - starting x coordinate.
starty - starting y coordinate.
endx - ending x coordinate.
endy - ending y coordinate.
duration - amount of time in milliseconds for the entire swipe action to take

**Example:**

```
 @Test
 public void swipingVertical() throws InterruptedException {
  //Get the size of screen.
  size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  System.out.println(size);

  //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
  //Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
  int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
  //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
  int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
  //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
  int startx = size.width / 2;
  System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

  //Swipe from Bottom to Top.
  driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  //Swipe from Top to Bottom.
  driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 3000);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
 }
```

This will definitely work for the new version of Java Client 4.0 to execute your Appium Script

Regards:
Gaurav Lad

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this response](https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-4-0-0-released/10434/12) on Appium's discussion board.

Basically, the same guts of the old scrolling methods are still available (Android/iOS ui automator); this just means that you can create your own helpers to suit your precise needs.